# Django 1.7: ManyToManyField giving no_such_table error

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have two models:

```
class Date(models.Model):
    MONTHS = (
        ('1', 'January'),
        ('2', 'February'),
        ('3', 'March'),
        ('4', 'April'),
        ('5', 'May'),
        ('6', 'June'),
        ('7', 'July'),
        ('8', 'August'),
        ('9', 'September'),
        ('10', 'October'),
        ('11', 'November'),
        ('12', 'December'),
    )
    month = models.CharField(max_length= 15, choices=MONTHS)

    def __str___(self):
        return self.month

class Plant(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=60)
    season = models.ManyToManyField(Date)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering=('name',)
```

My plan is to create 12 Date objects for each month.  Then I'm going to relate each Plant object to one or many months depending on which months they are in season.

The problem I'm having is that when I go into admin and try to create a Plant or Date object...I get an error which says:

no such table: [myappname]_date

For some reason when I migrate my tables, all the necessary tables are not being created.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So I went through and manually deleted all of my tables and then re-ran my migrations and everything works now.